# Fill large hole in mesh

Tags: edit-mode

sorry, I don't know what to search for here. I've downloaded an obj. It has a large hole in it that I would like to fill with mesh so I can sculpt it to fit in with the rest of the figure. I've filled in the small holes with edge select and grid fill but I can't edge select this large hole, it will only select sections which won't fill with anything but one face which won't subdivide.

The idea of manually trying to select hundreds of edges is really daunting and then I'm not even sure the grid fill would work. I'm sure the 'F' fill would work with one face but then, as above, I can't subdivide that.

So how can I easily fill a large hole with mesh without going mad? :)
Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Would you mind adding some images to your question, so we know what the 'hole in mesh' looks like? Thank you.

Comment: As far as i know there is no simple way for complex holes (would be glad if there was). Personally I use MeshLab’s (Filter>Remeshing>Close Holes) as a workaround with 3D Scan workflows. After that you can get good results with the new Blender Voxel Remesher and/or QuadriFlow Remesh.